# Getting data for multiple objects using django checkbox

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to get data of all objects that are selected in django admin panel using the checkbox but i can't get it right: class SalesView(View):

```
def get(self, request, sales):
    sales = SaleItem.objects.all()
```

i know i need to turn this all() function to filter to get id but just won't work!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, what do you mean with "to get id"?